# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conne'

Tags: python, multithreading, class, sockets, init

I have a problem with overriding the init method of the thread class.
I only need it to take a socket that i pass to the init method when I instantiate the thread object.
The code of the thread class is:

```
class client_handle(threading.Thread):

    conne = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self, conne=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, conne=conne)
```

When i create a client_handle object i write:

```
socket_conn, addr = s.accept()
client_thread = client_handle(socket_conn)
```

I also searched in other posts but i couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `conne` manually as attribute of the instance. Passing it as argument to `Thread.__init__` won't work (would be set as the group-argument of the Thread-class).

```
from threading import Thread

class ClientHandle(Thread):
    def __init__(self, conne=None):
        super().__init__() # Python 3
        self.conne = conne
```

Comment: Thank you it works. So, this will create the attribute conne that doesn't exist in the Thread class, right?

Comment: @Rasta Yes, it will for this new class. You inherit from `Thread` and re-define `__init__`, this overrides the inherited `__init__` so you have to call `__init__()` in the parent class like you do. Then you expand your new subclass with your new added attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.__init__` doesn't have a parameter named `conne`, so you have to pass the value as a positional argument instead.

```
def __init__(self, conne=None):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self, conne)
```

Incidentally, the class attribute `client_handle.conne` doesn't seem to serve any purpose; you can probably get rid of it.

Update: passing a socket to `Thread.__init__` in particular is clearly wrong, but this applies to any attempt to "invent" a parameter name like `conne` for a method that doesn't have a parameter named `conne`.

Comment: Not sure, But is there is any difference between `threading.Thread.__init__(self, conne)` and `super().__init__(self, conne)`

Comment: There is a subtle difference, but it only would become apparent in a subclass of `client_handle`. `threading.Thread.__init__` is a reference to a specific function; `super().__init__` is a reference to the `__init__` method of whatever class comes after `client_handle` in the the MRO of `type(self)`. If you are creating an instance of `client_handle`, though, `threading.Thread` *is* the next class in the MRO, so they are equivalent. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I wrote as you told me    conne instead of    conne=conne but now it gives me this error:    group argument must be None for now

Comment: Right; I forgot to look at what `Thread.__init__` wanted as an argument. What do you think the thread would do with a socket?

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the detailed explanation :)